# Build twnsorflow for win32

Tags: winapi, tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow for win32 with cmake. All is fine until it hit this line:
libprotobuf.lib(descriptor.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' [A:\src\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build32\proto_text.vcxproj]

Upon checking, the libprotobuf.lib is indeed built as a x64 binary.

So where should I change to make it build a win32 library?

Comment: if you want build x86 binary you must use x86 libs only. or if you want use x64 libs - you need build x64 binary target.

Comment: I just build tensorflow.dll on windows 32 bits. It's tensorflow.dll used for C++ linking. [Releases](https://github.com/thuanvh/tensorflow/releases), [README](https://github.com/thuanvh/tensorflow/blob/w32_xp/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar linking error when building 32bit tensorflow.dll.

I fixed the problem by manually changing the mangled name of `~OpDef` from

```
??1OpDef@tensorflow@@UEAA@XZ
```

to

```
??1OpDef@tensorflow@@UAE@XZ
```

(latter I found by running "`dumpbin /symbol`" on `op_def.pb.obj`)

Answer (score -1):

this problem is resolved. Apparently during building, tensorflow downloads protobuf, and the generated project file has target machine set to x64. So this was an easy fix.

Now I have encountered a new problem: during building of the pywrap_tensorflow_internal project, the following link error happened:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl tensorflow::OpDef::~OpDef(void)"

It looks the project is using __cdecl calling convention while the ~OpDef destructor is using __thiscall. And I can't change the calling convention of a class destructor. I have no idea how this could happen.

Any idea on how to fix this calling convention mismatch issue?